# How to add mapStateToProps / redux to react-navigation TabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I want to build the very simple example shown here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation.html

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // 1.0.0-beta.27

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
});
```

How would I go about wrapping the tab navigator in mapStateToProps (or any stack navigator). For example if I want to use dynamic tab names for a specific tab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const MainRoot =(props) => {
      const myTabbar = TabNavigator({
              Home: LoginForm,
              Settings: RegistrationForm,
              third: TabsView
               },{
               initialRouteName: props.myName
               }
             );
       return <CustomTabNavigator/>;
 }
 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
          myName: state.LibraryMain,
 });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainRoot)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.